# проблемы с русскими буквами в excel python

Tags: python, excel

код:

```
import csv

final = ['CS', 'Maxim Mernes', 'Crypto-Крипта | Новости криптовалют. Инвестиции и трейдинг | Биткоин и альткойны']

with open('data.csv', 'w',  encoding='utf-8')as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['channel name']) 
    
for objects in final:
    with open('data.csv', 'a',  encoding='utf-8')as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([objects])
```

А по итогу в таблице где на звания с Русским языком во так:

> Ethereum, ��������������, ����������������

Что делать, как добиться правильной кодировки?

Comment: А если в cp1251 сохранить, вместо utf-8?

Comment: не работает((((

Comment: Что, такие же кракозябры?

Comment: да и причем только русский язык

Comment: Поменял кодировку, добавил `newline=''`, чтобы не было лишних пустых строк и https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wRIV.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменил кодировку c `utf-8` на `cp1251`

```py
import csv

final = ['CS', 'Maxim Mernes', 'Crypto-Крипта | Новости криптовалют. Инвестиции и трейдинг | Биткоин и альткойны']

with open('data.csv', 'w',  encoding='cp1251')as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['channel name']) 
    
for objects in final:
    with open('data.csv', 'a',  encoding='cp1251')as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([objects])
```